# Two elements on one line, but not centering

Tags: css

When trying to place both an `<input>` and a `<select>` box and separating them with a grey line in between, it shows just how I want it.

The problem is that the two elements does not center like the rest. They stay all the way to the left. Does not the `text-align:center;` apply for these?

**CSS**

```
li{
float: left;
border-left: 2px solid #999999;
padding: 0 10px;
list-style-type: none;
}
li.f{
border: 0;
padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li class="f">
<select><option value="things">things</option></select>
</li>
<li>
<input type="checkbox">Check me
</li>
```

Comment: You're floating the li left... and why are those in a list? You do have those li tags wrapped in a ul or ol right?

Comment: @RickCalder I thought that was a good idea? I only need to find a way to center this. float:right/left does not work, I've tried :(

Comment: Centre it where? You're not giving any context to the code.

Comment: @RickCalder All the elements are following my rule text-align:center; (sorry for not providing the `body`), but not this one

Comment: Adam's answer then. Lists have base default styling of text-align:left you need to override that in your CSS.

Comment: @RickCalder Oh, it makes sense now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go:
[http://jsfiddle.net/YPyRF/36/](http://jsfiddle.net/YPyRF/35/)

You were floating your LI's left, so I replaced it with
`display:inline-block;` and I put `text-align:center;` on the UL.

CSS

```
li{
    display:inline-block;
    border-left: 2px solid #999999;
    padding: 0 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li.f{
    border: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
}
ul {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle links to an empty fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You could give `margin-left: 40%;` to your `li.f`, that value you can adjust it depending of the width of both **li's** so it gets centered, the `40%` seems fine for your fiddle.

here the [**demo**](https://tinker.io/49e9a)